# What does the word "book" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I came across this peculiar use of the word book:

[image]

Does it have the same meaning as a "pile" or a "bale" of hay?

Comment: I have no idea. I am a native English speaker in my sixties, and I have never enountered the phrase "a book of hay". The OED does not acknowledge such a meaning. My guess is that it is a misprint, but I'm not sure what for: perhaps _stook_? What age is the book.

Comment: Was it a mis-scanning of "[stook](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stook) of hay"? Apart from a [source of the quote](https://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/james-c-scott-two-cheers-for-anarchism) (and some travel guides) I can only find ["This is a book of hay, crows, clearings, roots and parishes"](https://www.arcpublications.co.uk/reviews/858).

Comment: Or possibly [cock of hay](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hay-cock)?

Comment: _I have a 14 year old stallion who I am going to be getting back in show shape for halter only. I need a neck sweat for him, and I will be lunging him daily. But, I have no idea how to approach his diet. We have him on Dumor complete 14% senior feed (2 quarts) and Dumor Joint supplement. Once a day with 2 books of hay a day also. (Alfalfa/timothy one in morning one at night.) I can't switch hay really, since we have to buy for the big horses as well._ - posted on a US horse-interest forum.

Comment: _I bought tightly baled mulch hay that comes apart in firm "tiles" or "books" ,whatever you want to call them. I pulled the bales apart into about 3 inch thick tiles and covered one of my 5X50 beds with them. It took 6 bales so im looking at 120 bales for all 20 of beds which is about $250-$300 dollars worth of mulch hay around here, plus 5 trips with the my little trailer._  - US farming forum

Comment: _as a midwest farmboy originally from illinois,weve had cattle and hay in our barns from the 1850s till i got out of farming in 1999,the correct term for a "book" of hay is called a flake.not trying to be snobish o know it all but impress your farm connections with the word flake and they probaly wont have quite the chuckle when u describe what u r doing.god bless_ - likewise.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Type out the part that you're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay is harvested and packaged into **bales**.

Due to the baling process, a bale of hay consists of several distinct units of compressed matter. Because each unit is itself very tightly compressed but only loosely pressed against its neighbor, it is easy to extract or break off only one unit at a time:

[image: A bale of hay with flakes partially separated]

As [this page](http://hayinabale.com/What-is-a-Flake.html) (which is the source of the image) explains, the units are called **flakes**.

But as Michael Harvey pointed out in the comments, some people might call the units **books** instead, probably because they look like a row of books lined up on a bookshelf.

Both **book** and **flake** can be used as a term of measurement, used to represent a given volume or mass of hay. But they are not standardized; a flake of hay is *around* five pounds but can vary depending on the type of material in the hay, the hay's moisture content, the equipment used to bale the hay, etc. The mass of a flake can even vary within the same bale. So your author describes it as a "vernacular" measurement rather than a scientific one.